# Form submit getting blank page(the address bar showing the php file name), but sending information well to my email id

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I do not want to redirect or refresh my page to different page after submission of form. After "submit" click i m getting the blank page, and the address bar showing the php file path. But i m receiving the form information into my mail id.

```
------------------------------------- html file
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank we received!"); 
            }); 
        });
```

```
<form id="myform" class="form-box"  method="post" action="post.php">
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text"  required placeholder="your Name *" size="20" maxlength="25" class="surnameInput" tabindex="1">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required placeholder="your email *" size="20" maxlength="30" class="mailInput" tabindex="2">
        <input id="desig" name="desig" type="text" placeholder="designation" size="20" maxlength="20" class="surnameInput" tabindex="3">
        <input id="mobile" name="mobile" type="tel" placeholder="mobile 10 digit" size="20" maxlength="10" class="phoneInput" tabindex="4">
        <textarea id="msg" name="msg" required placeholder="your message *" cols="20" rows="5" tabindex="5"></textarea>

    <div id="btn">  
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" tabindex="7">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  tabindex="6">
        <span id="error" style="display:none;  color:rgba(179,7,7,1);">Please fill up the mandatory information !</span>
        <span id="success" style="display:none; color:rgba(29,183,5,1);">Thank you, We got your message !!!</span>
    </div>                
    </form>
```

-----------------------------------------php file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{

    //print_r($_POST);
    $to = "here my email id"; 
        $name = trim($_POST['name']); 
        $email = trim($_POST['email']); 
        $designation = trim($_POST['desig']); 
        $mobile = trim($_POST['mobile']); 
        $message = trim($_POST['msg']);      
        $subject = "Message from abcd.com"; 
        $headers = "From: $email";   
        $messages = "Name: $name 
        Email: $email 
        Designation: $designation 
        Mobile: $mobile  
        Message: $message"; 
        $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $messages, $headers); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. You can however redirect the user back after sending the email like so:

`header('Location: /theformpage.html');`

Comment: pls guide me i m beginner in php, where to place the header()
i placed like this, but not working

$mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $messages, $headers); 
header('Location: /contactus.html');

Comment: Is there no redirect at all, or is it redirecting to the wrong location?

Comment: I m getting mail after submit btn click, but the page is blank and no progress to any other page. The address bar showing the path of my php file.
Can any one pls guide
i do not want to redirect this page to another html page, nor i want to c the page refresh also.

Comment: For very simple sites it's usually acceptable to handle the email logic in the same file (make sure to change the ending to .php and to set the form action accordingly). Here's an example of how to do it, with the PHP logic at the top and your regular HTML page below: http://blog.justin.kelly.org.au/simple-1-page-phpjquery-contact-form/

Comment: Thank u so much sir :), its a great help to me